# Do any Hindu deities take onion and garlic?

Tags: gods, goddess, non-vegetarian

I have seen many Hindu deities being offered meat (mainly the Goddesses) and alcohol. However, are there any Hindu deities who are offered onion and garlic?

Comment: Well you are free to offer anything, a person can offer himself as well but that does not mean that deities consume it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have seen many Hindu deities being offered meat (mainly the
>   Goddesses) and alcohol.

You might have seen that but what you have missed seeing is that they are purified meat-alcohol. All the Pancha-Dravvyas are first purified using mostly Vedic and Agamic mantras. Only then they are considered fit to be used in rituals.

What happens when one uses anyone of the Pancha Tattvas, without purifying them first, is mentioned in the verse given below:

> **Asamaskritam pived** dravyam balAtkArena maithunam |
>  Swapriyena hatam
>   mAmsam rauravam narakam vrajet ||
>
> .............
>
> **One who drinks unpurified Madya**, one who uses forcefully the
>   Pancha-Dravvyas, or who kills beings for one's own use visits the hell
>   called Raurava.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 5-99**

The respective Mantras, which purify the 5 Dravyas are given in Agamas.

As regards, Madya or VAruni, it was originally pure (iT came out of the Samudra Manthana). Its only after the [Sukra-Kacha episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kacha_(sage)) took place, that the Daitya Guru SukrAcharya cursed it to become impure.

The curse removal Mantra (which ends with SudhA Devyai Namaha) is used to re-purify Madya to make it fit again to be consumed.

As regards meat, the Manu Smriti says the following:

> Manu Smriti 5.36. A Brahmana must never eat (the flesh of animals
>   unhallowed by Mantras; **but, obedient to the primeval law, he may eat
>   it, consecrated with Vedic texts.**

And, the same procedure of making MAmasa pure is used in Tantrik rituals (the ones that use Panacha-MakAra that is).

Now, coming to garlic and onion, they are not fit to be offered to any Deity. Even, if meat or fish is offered to a Deity, they are prepared without the use of garlic-onion. You can yourself verify it from the temples where you saw meat being offered.

> Manu Smriti 5.5. Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and (all plants), springing from impure (substances), are unfit to be eaten by twice-born men.

Comment: Can you please provide the mantra to purify alcohol and meat?

Comment: They are secret mantras to be used only by qualified sadhakas. Without Diksha one should not use them. Also, they are to be used only in rituals not while eating meat etc for our own pleasure @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: Even purified alcohol cannot be used for one's own pleasure?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I am not sure because no Texts allow using alcohol for personal use. Only can be used while performing certain rituals.

Comment: Prabhupada says meat addicts are allowed to sacrifice meat to Maa Kali twice a month for their own use. Is he correct?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury No texts allow killing for our own pleasure. However if done for Pitru-Deva karyas they don't incur sin. Also, there is nothing like twice a month thrice a month etc.